# App vs package - This app is using a deprecated version of the Android embedding

Tags: flutter

```
 flutter --version
Flutter 3.4.0-29.0.pre.115 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision ab254fae93 (19 hours ago) • 2022-09-23 12:53:30 -0400
Engine • revision 3d7450f2cd
Tools • Dart 2.19.0 (build 2.19.0-235.0.dev) • DevTools 2.17.0
```

When creating a package `flutter create --template=package hello`
I get:

```
This app is using a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to migrate this app to the V2 embedding.
Take a look at the docs for migrating an app: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects
```

Ok you could go through the process of upgrading following the link.

I would rather not use time on that, so my question is - are there any different in creating an app `flutter create --org com.appsyouwear -i swift -a java --description $DESCRIPTION, $NAME` from creating a template=package - the pubspect looks the same?

Also when creating a package - not a plugin, why generate platform code?